# As verb, "care of something" or "care something"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I wonder when "care" is used as a verb, what differences are between "care of something/somebody" and "care something/somebody", besides that "care" is used as a v.i. in the first one and v.t. in the second one.

For example:

> Money is the least thing I should care (of).

Which one is better here?

Comment: Eh? I'm sorry, but I can't make heads or tails of your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context you gave, *about* would be better:

> Money is the least thing I should care about.

I agree with cornbreadninja about the word *least*, though.  *Last* sounds more natural:

> Money is the last thing I should care about.

*Care of* is not used as a verb phrase.  Likewise with *care*.  You cannot *care of* something, and you also cannot *care* something.  A legitimate verb phrase using *care of* is *[take care of](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+care+of)*, which means *protect/meet the needs of*.  Also, as FumbleFingers says below, *care of* is possible when *care* is a noun.

As a side note, if you ever see the common phrase *care for*, bear in mind that its meaning is different from *care about*, especially when used with a negative.

If you *don't* care for something, it means you don't like/prefer it.

If you *do* care for something, it means you take care of it.

Comment: haha you are too fast for me. Yes, but I'll reverse it now!

Comment: Mind you, you can *care for* your ageing relatives, in the sense of "look after". It's only when negated that you get the "be [un]interested in" sense.

Comment: @Tim: You can speak of *"care of the elderly"*, but that's a **noun**, and has different sense to yours. When you use *"care"* as a verb, you don't follow it with *"of"*.

Answer (score 3):

You would want to say

> Money is the least thing I should care *about*.

but this is somewhat clunky.  A less clunky version would be *Money is the thing about which I care the least* or *Money is the **last** thing I care about*.